# Template error C2244 unable to match function definition to an existing declaration using constexpr in Microsoft Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, constexpr

I'm the getting : error C2244 unable to match function definition to an existing declaration while using *constexpr*.

```
template<int N> constexpr int x() {
    return N*N;
}

template<int X, int N> class B {
public:
    int data;
};

template<int N> class A {
public:
    int f(B<x<N>(), N> b);
};

template<int N> int A<N>::f(B<x<N>(), N> b) {
    return b.data;
}

int main() {
    A<10> a;
    return 0;
}
```

If I remove *constexpr* function and replace with expression *N*N*, then everything works fine.

GNU C++ compiles it and I expect, according to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx, that *constexpr* works correctly on  Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Code looks fine, gcc and clang think it is fine -> My money is not on MSVC.

Comment: Visual Studio 2015's `constexpr` support is still somewhat lacking. IIRC, their support only goes up to C++11 `constexpr`, and a tiny subset of C++14 `constexpr` features.

Comment: The issue is still present in 2017 RC, so I think you should report it on Connect.